# Account linking and google api

Tags: php, google-plus, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-profiles-api

I've implemented the account linking in streamlined identity flow (https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-assertion-flow)

```
// Get the jwt token from the request
    $token = $this->jwt->parse($body['assertion']);

    if (null === Client::where('id', $body['client_id'])->where('secret', $body['client_secret'])->first()
        && (false === $this->verifySignature($token) || false === $this->validateData($token))
    ) {
        return response()->json(
            [
                'error' => 'invalid_grant',
            ],
            Http::UNAUTHORIZED
        );
    }

    $sub = $token->getClaim('sub');
    $email = $token->getClaim('email');
    $scopes = explode(' ', $body['scope']);

    // Check if the user exists in the database or not
    $userId = User::findIdByGoogleIds($email, $sub);
    \Log::debug($userId);

    // If user doesn't exists and intent is get, ask google to send you the create intent with all user info.
    if (null === $userId && 'get' === $body['intent']) {
        \Log::debug('user not found, ask for a create request');

        return response()->json(
            [
                'error' => 'user_not_found',
            ],
            Http::UNAUTHORIZED
        );

    // If user doesn't exist and we are in intent create, let's create this user in our database.
    } elseif (null === $userId && 'create' === $body['intent']) {
        \Log::debug('user not found, create it');

        // If user exists bug don't have the google profile associated.
        if (null === ($user = User::findByMail($email))) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->password = Hash::make(str_random(8));
            $user->email = $email;
            $user->name = $token->getClaim('name');

            $user->save();
            //Generate a token for the user
            static::generateToken($user, $scopes);
        }

        // Asssociate google profile that user
        $profile = new GoogleProfile();
        $profile->google_id = $sub;
        $user->googleProfiles()->save($profile);

    } elseif (null !== $userId) {
        \Log::debug('google profile already existing');

        $user = User::find($userId->id);
    }
```

The JWT Token contain that informations :

```
{
  "sub": 1234567890,        // The unique ID of the user's Google Account
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",        // The assertion's issuer
  "aud": "123-abc.apps.googleusercontent.com", // Your server's client ID
  "iat": 233366400,         // Unix timestamp of the assertion's creation time
  "exp": 233370000,         // Unix timestamp of the assertion's expiration time
  "name": "Jan Jansen",
  "given_name": "Jan",
  "family_name": "Jansen",
  "email": "jan@gmail.com", // If present, the user's email address
  "locale": "en_US"
}
```

And I need to get the phone number filled by the user in his google profile (if there is one).

So i were thinking to use google + api, so I'm trying this :

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('my_client_id');
    $client->setClientSecret('my_client_secret');
    $client->setAccessToken($token->getPayload());
    $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);

    $test = $plus->people->get($sub);
```

the client_id and secret have been created on https://console.developers.google.com

The response is :

```
 {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
 {"exception":"[object] (Google_Service_Exception(code: 401): {
 \"error\": {
  \"errors\": [
   {
    \"domain\": \"global\",
    \"reason\": \"authError\",
    \"message\": \"Invalid Credentials\",
    \"locationType\": \"header\",
    \"location\": \"Authorization\"
   }
  ],
  \"code\": 401,
  \"message\": \"Invalid Credentials\"
 }
}
```

So, on what I understand, the account linking is an OAuth authentication, so it should send me a valid token access that I can use with the google api.
But it's telling me that this token is invalid.

Am I missing something or i'm not doing that in the good way? 
Do I have to do again a new authentication specific to google api?

Comment: Please update the question to show what you've done so far and what specifically isn't working for you

Comment: This isn’t a site to ask for full code samples or tutorials. Please go read [ask] first of all.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code that you're currently using to get user information and what API you think you can use to get phone number information.

Comment: I've updated my initial post with informations you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems with how you're doing what you want to do.

First, the token you're getting in `assertion` is an Identity Token, not an Authorization Token. The token itself is not a bearer token that authorizes you to do anything on the user's behalf. The guidelines you point to about the assertion flow says that you should verify the token and then use this to get the unique ID of the user from the `sub` field. You should use this ID to determine if the user has already authenticated in your system and use the Auth Token and Refresh Token that you have for the user.

Second, you probably don't want the Google+ API since the [Google+ People object](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people) doesn't include a field for phone number. If it did, and if you wanted to use the "me" parameter to get private info about the user, you would have needed to request either the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` auth scopes when the user logs in.

Instead, you probably want to use the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/read-people). The [people object](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people) contains the [phone numbers](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.PhoneNumber) which you can retrieve using the [get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) method, but there are some restrictions:

- They actually have to have set the phone number and you need to request that field as one of the fields to fetch
- If they have made it public, you should be able to get it.
- If they have *not* made it public, you'll need to request the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read` scope.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment concerning the id flow and auth flow, i'm going to change all that and handle it differently.

Comment: If this has answered your question, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.